# Using a content script to modify an html page that is part of a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension and wondering if it is possible to use a content script to modify an html page that is part of the chrome extension?

The background script creates a new tab and displays the included html page.  I wanted to modify the content of that html page based on settings in the extension options page.

Comment: No need to use a content script. Simply include the js file using `<script src=` in your html page.

Comment: I found an alternate way of doing what I was trying to accomplish using chrome.storage. But I would still be interested to know the answer to the original question.